# mysql joining 4 tables with md5 columns

Tags: php, mysql, join, view

I have four big tables in mysql connected with the md5 string as below

main table has the md5 string as the primary key say

```
table1-|md5_col1|col2|....
table2-|same_md5_frm_table1|col2|col3|....
table3-|same_md5_frm_table1|col2|col3|....
table4-|same_md5_frm_table1|col2|col3|....
```

when I make join (inner or left or right) the mysql service is getting stopped.

I have made a view making all the columns joined together and when fetch from view the mysql service is getting stopped.

Even when I select very less columns the mysql service is getting stopped.

Tried many way but no result..

Can any one help me how to get the result from all the four tables?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the mysql-service stops when you send a query with a JOIN? if that's true, there must be something seriously wrong with your server configuration.

Comment: did you try view? and all indexes are defined correctly?

Comment: How big are these tables? I'd it just your connection timing out or is the MySQL service actually stopping to the point that you have to start it back up?

Comment: I tried view also, when I try to show the records in the view mysql hangs up.

Comment: How can I configure mysql server ?

Comment: there are 2 lakhs records in the table